# Show differential equation $y(y^2+2x)+2x(y^2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ has integrating factor of form $\mu=x^2y^k$ Find the general solution to this equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I really dont know where to start this one. Ive been going round in circles just trying to simplify the equation...

Any tips on how to start this? Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: The words *integrating factor* are a clue.  Do you know what they mean?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the integrating factor then if you multiply it to the equation, you should obtain an exact equation... from there you should be able to use the method of exact equation to solve this problem. 
So to show that the DE have the integrating factor of that form, show that the cross partial are equal.